# Search and print text file using java

Tags: java, search, text, printing

How do i search for a text and print out a specific line of text from a .txt file?
e.g. i have a txt file called airlines.txt and i search for MMHHHAAAA. Then, I want to extract "Malaysian Airlines" from the line "MMHHHAAAA:Malaysian Airlines"

```
//Scan file airlines.txt
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("airlines.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
//Will this work?
  String s = scan.nextLine();
  Scanner line = new Scanner(s);
  String airline;
//How do i continue from here to scan for MMHHHAAAA and then print out the following line of text
}
System.out.println("Airline is" + airline);
return airline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in Java 8:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("airlines.txt");

final Optional<String> theLine;

try (
    final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
) {
    theLine = lines.filter(s -> s.startsWith("MMHHHAAAA:"))
        .findFirst();
}

if (theLine.isPresent())
    // do something with theLine.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `String.indexOf("")` method.

```
if (s.indexOf("your-search-string") != -1) {
   //matched the pattern
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

You can use `substring()` to extract the part after `:`.
`System.out.println(s.substring(":"));`

Read more about [Java strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and its methods.

Comment: This is missing how to extract the part of the string after the ":".

Answer (score 0):

One possibility...

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("airlines.txt"));
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

      String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
      if(currentLine.indexOf("MMHHHAAAA") != -1){
          String airline = currentLine.split(":")[1];
          System.out.println("Airline is " + airline);
      }
    }
```